# How to Obtain the 'id' of '$(this)' in jQuery After Event Delegation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user click on a particular post with `class="home"`, I would like to perform Ajax call and send the `id` of that particular post to the server. Because the post is being looped through the `HTML` page when it is rendered, each post has the same `class` but different `id`. The code looks like this:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on('click','.home', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  //How do I get the 'id' of the clicked post only?
  var id = $(this).id;
  var url = "/home" + id;
  //This currently shows 'undefined'.
  console.log(id);
  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "POST",
  }).done(function(result){
      //action taken...
  }).fail(function(err){
      console.log(err);
  });
});
```

Currently, I am using `var id = $(this).id` to get the `id` of the clicked post. However, I think it's not correct as I believe `this` doesn't refer to anything here. I tried other methods but it didn't help.

Comment: You tried `$(document).on('submit','.post',function(){})` ?

Comment: I just found out that that's working fine, it's the `id` that's not working. Sorry about that.

Just wondering, after `$(document).on('submit','.post',function(){})`, how do you get the `id` of the `.post` that has been submitted?

Comment: Edit your question with an example of your HTML code.

Comment: Inside your function you can try var id = $(this).id;

Comment: It says `undefined` when I `console.log(id)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to get the id of $(this) in an event function is

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

id is a property of a DOM element, not a jQuery object. So you could as an alternative get the HTML element associated with $(this) using get() and then get the id property of that:

```
var id = $(this).get(0).id;
```

Either of these will work.